# Change background color of comments Wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

How to I change the background color of the comments posted? I have white text so the text is not visible

[image]

Comment: You change it with `CSS`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm kind of new to WP, so its hard for me to find the Stylesheets, half are on GoDaddy, and half are on WP, its just weird. I just need to know which stylesheet to edit

Comment: Try to find out relevant CSS code using firebug. and then you can fix this problem by yourself.

Comment: Thanks both for your replies. Think firebug solved all my problems. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

use chrome to open any post which have comment, then right click on the comment and select 'inspect element'. Now you will see the relevant CSS where you can make changes as per your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

change the background color using CSS and tha file might be located in wordpress/wp-content/themes/style.css or in wordpress/wp-content/themes/css/style.css
or get any css file and add new style for #comment